# if array value is the same then add to the existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I have been fighting with this all day and would like another set of eyes to maybe give me some insight. I'm not sure I am even approaching this the correct way. I have an array that lists out products bought, however if the product is duplicated in the array I want to merge the attributes together.

```
$order = $order->getProducts();
$newArray = array();
foreach ($order as $order)
{
    $product = new Product($order['product_id']);

    $combination = new Combination($order['product_attribute_id']);
    $attribute = $combination->getAttributesName($context->language->id);
    foreach ($attribute as $attribute)
        $attributeName = $attribute['name'];

    $newArray[] = array(
        'id_product' => $order['product_id'],
        'name' => $product->name[$context->language->id],
        'combination' => array(
            'id_product_attribute' => $order['product_attribute_id'],
            'type' => $attributeName
        )
    );
}
```

My array comes out looking like this

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id_product] => 117
        [name] => Sidewinder 1-Foot Extension
        [combination] => Array
            (
                [id_product_attribute] => 172
                [type] => Black
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id_product] => 117
        [name] => Sidewinder 1-Foot Extension
        [combination] => Array
            (
                [id_product_attribute] => 173
                [type] => Black & Yellow
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id_product] => 119
        [name] => ENV100
        [combination] => Array
            (
                [id_product_attribute] => 0
                [type] => Black & Yellow
            )

    )

)
```

I am wanting to try to achieve this

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id_product] => 117
        [name] => Sidewinder 1-Foot Extension
        [combination] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                         [id_product_attribute] => 172
                         [type] => Black
                    )
                 [1] => Array
                    (
                         [id_product_attribute] => 173
                         [type] => Black & Yellow
                    )
            )

    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id_product] => 119
        [name] => ENV100
        [combination] => Array
            (
                [id_product_attribute] => 0
                [type] => 
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: array_merge_recursive

Comment: Store `id_product` in some kind of lookup table - key is `id_product`, value is index in `newArray`

Comment: if you use id_product as the array key, this will make life a lot easier, otherwise you have to loop the whole thing every time to find which sub-array to add to.

Comment: @Dagon I didn't think of that. Good Idea! Will try it out.

Comment: Can you post an example of `var_dump($product);` and of `var_dump($combination)`?  The `foreach ($attribute as $attribute) $attributeName = $attribute['name'];` without any `{}` enclosure is confusing here.

Comment: I took a stab without seeing any benefit to `foreach ($attribute as $attribute)
        $attributeName = $attribute['name'];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be able to make it look a little better, but this should work:

```
foreach ($order as $order) {
    $product = new Product($order['product_id']);
    $combination = new Combination($order['product_attribute_id']);
    $attribute = $combination->getAttributesName($context->language->id);

    $newArray[$order['product_id']] = array(
            'id_product' => $order['product_id'],
            'name' => $product->name[$context->language->id],
    );

    foreach ($attribute as $attr) {        
        $newArray[$order['product_id']]['combination'][] => array(
                'id_product_attribute' => $attr['id'], // a guess
                'type' => $attr['name'],
        );
    }
}
```

The array keys will be the `product_id` so if you want them as you show, then after the loop:

```
$newArray = array_values($newArray);
```

I took a stab without knowing what this is meant to do:

```
foreach ($attribute as $attribute)
        $attributeName = $attribute['name'];
```

Comment: The core function combinations->getAttributesName returns a multidimensional array and I used that to access the name. This piece you wrote does work however it isn't adding to the combination array. Just adding the last one within the array it hit

Comment: Last edit.  Notice the `'id_product_attribute'` will need to be from the `$attribute` array and not `$order`.  Best I can do without all arrays structures.